# Does Chrome have a quick find shortcut similar to ' in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I absolutely lived on the `'` shortcut in Firefox, which allows you to do a find that applies to text links, and it focuses on them so you can hit `Enter` and proceed to that link.

Chrome only has `ctrl-f` which focuses on links as well, but you have to `ESC` out and then hit `Enter`, which is not as immediate as the Firefox shortcut.

Is anyone aware of a Chrome shortcut that replicates this functionality? Or is there some hidden shortcut/key that does this in Chrome which I'm simply unaware of?

Comment: I did not know this shortcut before, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have only just found out that you could esc-out and enter. +1 and thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be a native solution but you could use Chromium and use this extension: http://code.google.com/p/chrome-type-ahead/

Answer (score 6):

In current versions of chrome you can do:

> Ctrl + F, < search query >, Ctrl + Enter

Which is a bit more convenient compared to using ESC.

Source: [How to do a quick find with forward slash in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/80819/how-to-do-a-quick-find-with-forward-slash-in-chrome/318194#318194)

Comment: Not *quite* the same. I believe is the equivalent of a `/` quick search in Firefox (which searches everything), what the question here wants is how to do a `'` quick search (which *only* searches links).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best plugin to enable this on Chrome (currently) is [Quick Find for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-find-for-google-chr/dejblhmebonldngnmeidliaifgiagcjj). Unfortunately Chrome doesn't have this feature by default.